# How can android interact with C# code?

Tags: c#, android

I want to develope an Android app that interacts with C# (just sending strings back and forth at first). However I have nou experience with listening to ports and getting data from them in either language. The PC and device will be on the same network. What "basic code" do I need to begin sending string values between Android and C#?

Comment: Does the PC need to "push" to Android, or will Android poll the PC periodically for new information, or is communication always a request/response pair, ...?

Comment: Did you see monoandroid?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I think it is best if its possible to push, then it would seem more responsive than waiting a set period to refresh.

Comment: I have been looking into this topic for a few days now and nothing about monoandroid came up. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want asynchronous, random communication between the two.  One sends the other some data, and the other sends a response of some sort?

You probably want sockets.  http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/

It's quite similar on the C# side.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks Simon, I am looking in to it and will let you know if it helps.

Comment: This is the best answer, but i found that the android apps need to redirect ports in order to work, so it is not currently working on my phone, only the emulator

Answer (score 0):

If it is client to server communication I would recommend using either JSON or XML on your server. In the past I have tried using KSOAP as the library on the client but it was a pain. I would get the server to print JSON using a rest approach. 
eg www.myamazingapp.com/givemethedatababy.asp

Inside of android you would make a request to the URL above using either a Async task or intent service. Android will crash if you try and make any requests on the UI thread so using these methods will fix that.

Once you have the the string parsed into a variable I would use an arraylist to bring it into memory.

Sorry if this is vague but the overall thought process of this can be a little hard to get your head around at first.

Go check out vogella.de for android web service stuff it will give you tons of information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jake, you are right, it is a hard concept to grasp, but i am looking into it.

Comment: Yes also you will want to check out arraylists in java as well if you are going to be bring back any data from servers are you familiar with them?

Comment: I am familiar with arraylists and have used them a lot, but I still can't figure out how they C# side of things work. I am trying  the C# side first because i have more experiance in it, or so I thought.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to a web service, for example i use android xml rpc, a server on my android waiting incoming data and you can do typically the same with your C#

The only thing you will need is the **redir add tcp** to send data through in or out of your emulator. see [here} (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) in the **emulator  networking** section for medtail

ps: Xml rpc is easily impementable and it s quite light for both android and c# classes